# Xcode 11.4 Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped

Tags: ios, xcode

When I archive with Xcode 11.4, it gives me warnings saying `Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped`. It's really annoying.

I don't know how to eliminate them. Does anybody know the reason or how to eliminate them?

The full-length log:

```
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !52), !dbg !199
label %29
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*, %"__ir_hidden#29_"**)* @sqliterkOpen
!52 = !DILabel(scope: !53, name: "sqliterkOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 90)
!53 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 57, type: !54, scopeLine: 60, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !178, retainedNodes: !193)
!199 = !DILocation(line: 90, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#33_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 57, type: !11, scopeLine: 60, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !52), !dbg !199
label %31
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*, %"__ir_hidden#29_"**)* @sqliterkOpen
!52 = !DILabel(scope: !53, name: "sqliterkOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 90)
!53 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 57, type: !54, scopeLine: 60, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !178, retainedNodes: !193)
!199 = !DILocation(line: 90, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#33_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 57, type: !11, scopeLine: 60, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !367), !dbg !376
label %18
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#29_"*, i32)* @sqliterkParsePage
!367 = !DILabel(scope: !368, name: "sqliterkParsePage_End", file: !10, line: 133)
!368 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkParsePage", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 117, type: !369, scopeLine: 118, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !178, retainedNodes: !371)
!376 = !DILocation(line: 133, column: 1, scope: !351)
!351 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#24_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 117, type: !11, scopeLine: 118, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!178 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !179, retainedTypes: !180, imports: !181, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !80), !dbg !230
label %65
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#29_"*, %"__ir_hidden#30_"*, i32, %"__ir_hidden#34_"**)* @sqliterkBtreeOpen
!80 = !DILabel(scope: !81, name: "sqliterkBtreeOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 116)
!81 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkBtreeOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 59, type: !82, scopeLine: 63, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !187, retainedNodes: !223)
!230 = !DILocation(line: 116, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#86_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 59, type: !11, scopeLine: 63, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !610) #13, !dbg !677
label %343
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#34_"*, i32)* @"\01__hidden#66_"
!610 = !DILabel(scope: !611, name: "sqliterkBtreeParseColumn_End", file: !10, line: 477)
!611 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkBtreeParsePayload", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 332, type: !612, scopeLine: 337, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !187, retainedNodes: !617)
!677 = !DILocation(line: 477, column: 1, scope: !443, inlinedAt: !444)
!443 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#81_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 332, type: !11, scopeLine: 337, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !691) #13, !dbg !713
label %359
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#34_"*, i32)* @"\01__hidden#66_"
!691 = !DILabel(scope: !692, name: "sqliterkBtreeParsePayload_End", file: !10, line: 319)
!692 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkBtreeParseCell", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 274, type: !693, scopeLine: 278, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !187, retainedNodes: !696)
!713 = !DILocation(line: 319, column: 1, scope: !430, inlinedAt: !431)
!430 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#80_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 274, type: !11, scopeLine: 278, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !721), !dbg !747
label %371
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#34_"*, i32)* @"\01__hidden#66_"
!721 = !DILabel(scope: !722, name: "sqliterkBtreeParsePage_End", file: !10, line: 256)
!722 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkBtreeParsePage", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 145, type: !723, scopeLine: 146, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !187, retainedNodes: !725)
!747 = !DILocation(line: 256, column: 1, scope: !324)
!324 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#79_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 145, type: !11, scopeLine: 146, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!187 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !188, retainedTypes: !197, globals: !200, imports: !211, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !26), !dbg !67
label %17
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#36_"**)* @sqliterkColumnAlloc
!26 = !DILabel(scope: !27, name: "sqliterkColumnAlloc_Failed", file: !10, line: 52)
!27 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkColumnAlloc", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 30, type: !28, scopeLine: 31, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !52, retainedNodes: !63)
!67 = !DILocation(line: 52, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#95_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 30, type: !11, scopeLine: 31, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!52 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !12, imports: !53, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !124), !dbg !243
label %85
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#30_"*, %"__ir_hidden#31_"*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*)* @sqliterkCryptoSetCipher
!124 = !DILabel(scope: !125, name: "bail_sqlite_errstr", file: !11, line: 213)
!125 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkCryptoSetCipher", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 133, type: !126, scopeLine: 136, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !182, retainedNodes: !224)
!243 = !DILocation(line: 213, column: 1, scope: !33)
!33 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#100_", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 133, type: !12, scopeLine: 136, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !242), !dbg !247
label %89
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#30_"*, %"__ir_hidden#31_"*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*)* @sqliterkCryptoSetCipher
!242 = !DILabel(scope: !125, name: "bail", file: !11, line: 218)
!125 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkCryptoSetCipher", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 133, type: !126, scopeLine: 136, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !182, retainedNodes: !224)
!247 = !DILocation(line: 218, column: 1, scope: !33)
!33 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#100_", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 133, type: !12, scopeLine: 136, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !279), !dbg !292
label %23
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#32_"*, i32, i8*)* @sqliterkCryptoDecode
!279 = !DILabel(scope: !280, name: "bail", file: !11, line: 260)
!280 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkCryptoDecode", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 233, type: !281, scopeLine: 234, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !182, retainedNodes: !283)
!292 = !DILocation(line: 260, column: 1, scope: !260)
!260 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#97_", scope: !11, file: !11, line: 233, type: !12, scopeLine: 234, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!182 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !183, retainedTypes: !184, imports: !214, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !53), !dbg !124
label %35
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#31_"**)* @sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen
!53 = !DILabel(scope: !54, name: "sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 70)
!54 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 36, type: !55, scopeLine: 37, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !71, retainedNodes: !118)
!124 = !DILocation(line: 70, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#115_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 36, type: !11, scopeLine: 37, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !53), !dbg !124
label %37
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#31_"**)* @sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen
!53 = !DILabel(scope: !54, name: "sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 70)
!54 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkOSReadOnlyOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 36, type: !55, scopeLine: 37, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !71, retainedNodes: !118)
!124 = !DILocation(line: 70, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#115_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 36, type: !11, scopeLine: 37, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!71 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !72, retainedTypes: !81, globals: !88, imports: !99, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !429), !dbg !4908
label %354
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#29_"*, %"__ir_hidden#143_"*, %"__ir_hidden#144_"*, i32, i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#29_"*, %"__ir_hidden#38_"*, %"__ir_hidden#36_"*)*, i8*)* @sqliterk_output_cb
!429 = !DILabel(scope: !430, name: "cancelled", file: !10, line: 572)
!430 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_output_cb", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 418, type: !431, scopeLine: 427, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !4851)
!4908 = !DILocation(line: 572, column: 1, scope: !15)
!15 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#303_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 418, type: !11, scopeLine: 427, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6205), !dbg !6371
label %261
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#143_"*, i8*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterk_save_master
!6205 = !DILabel(scope: !6206, name: "bail_zlib", file: !10, line: 814)
!6206 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_save_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !6207, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6209)
!6371 = !DILocation(line: 814, column: 1, scope: !6003)
!6003 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#272_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !11, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6368), !dbg !6374
label %267
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#143_"*, i8*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterk_save_master
!6368 = !DILabel(scope: !6206, name: "bail_errno", file: !10, line: 818)
!6206 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_save_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !6207, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6209)
!6374 = !DILocation(line: 818, column: 1, scope: !6003)
!6003 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#272_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !11, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6369), !dbg !6376
label %274
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#143_"*, i8*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterk_save_master
!6369 = !DILabel(scope: !6206, name: "bail_sqlite", file: !10, line: 821)
!6206 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_save_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !6207, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6209)
!6376 = !DILocation(line: 821, column: 1, scope: !6003)
!6003 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#272_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !11, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6370), !dbg !6378
label %279
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#143_"*, i8*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterk_save_master
!6370 = !DILabel(scope: !6206, name: "bail", file: !10, line: 825)
!6206 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_save_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !6207, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6209)
!6378 = !DILocation(line: 825, column: 1, scope: !6003)
!6003 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#272_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 632, type: !11, scopeLine: 636, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6647), !dbg !6685
label %275
i32 (i8*, i8*, i32, i8**, i32, %"__ir_hidden#144_"**, i8*)* @sqliterk_load_master
!6647 = !DILabel(scope: !6648, name: "bail_errno", file: !10, line: 1003)
!6648 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_load_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !6649, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6651)
!6685 = !DILocation(line: 1003, column: 1, scope: !6404)
!6404 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#260_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !11, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6683), !dbg !6688
label %286
i32 (i8*, i8*, i32, i8**, i32, %"__ir_hidden#144_"**, i8*)* @sqliterk_load_master
!6683 = !DILabel(scope: !6648, name: "bail_zlib", file: !10, line: 1007)
!6648 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_load_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !6649, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6651)
!6688 = !DILocation(line: 1007, column: 1, scope: !6404)
!6404 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#260_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !11, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !6684), !dbg !6691
label %290
i32 (i8*, i8*, i32, i8**, i32, %"__ir_hidden#144_"**, i8*)* @sqliterk_load_master
!6684 = !DILabel(scope: !6648, name: "bail", file: !10, line: 1010)
!6648 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterk_load_master", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !6649, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !2910, retainedNodes: !6651)
!6691 = !DILocation(line: 1010, column: 1, scope: !6404)
!6404 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#260_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 879, type: !11, scopeLine: 886, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!2910 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C_plus_plus, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !2911, retainedTypes: !3000, globals: !3974, imports: !3982, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !94), !dbg !191
label %94
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*, %"__ir_hidden#30_"**)* @sqliterkPagerOpen
!94 = !DILabel(scope: !95, name: "sqliterkPagerOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 127)
!95 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkPagerOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 41, type: !96, scopeLine: 44, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !153, retainedNodes: !175)
!191 = !DILocation(line: 127, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#344_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 41, type: !11, scopeLine: 44, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !94), !dbg !191
label %96
i32 (i8*, %"__ir_hidden#28_"*, %"__ir_hidden#30_"**)* @sqliterkPagerOpen
!94 = !DILabel(scope: !95, name: "sqliterkPagerOpen_Failed", file: !10, line: 127)
!95 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkPagerOpen", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 41, type: !96, scopeLine: 44, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !153, retainedNodes: !175)
!191 = !DILocation(line: 127, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#344_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 41, type: !11, scopeLine: 44, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !333), !dbg !351
label %167
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#30_"*, i32)* @"\01__hidden#317_"
!333 = !DILabel(scope: !334, name: "sqliterkPagerParseHeader_End", file: !10, line: 278)
!334 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkPagerParseHeader", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 137, type: !335, scopeLine: 138, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !153, retainedNodes: !337)
!351 = !DILocation(line: 278, column: 1, scope: !198)
!198 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#343_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 137, type: !11, scopeLine: 138, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !333), !dbg !351
label %169
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#30_"*, i32)* @"\01__hidden#317_"
!333 = !DILabel(scope: !334, name: "sqliterkPagerParseHeader_End", file: !10, line: 278)
!334 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkPagerParseHeader", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 137, type: !335, scopeLine: 138, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !153, retainedNodes: !337)
!351 = !DILocation(line: 278, column: 1, scope: !198)
!198 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#343_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 137, type: !11, scopeLine: 138, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !490), !dbg !511
label %64
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#30_"*, i32, %"__ir_hidden#35_"**, i32)* @"\01__hidden#318_"
!490 = !DILabel(scope: !491, name: "sqliterkPageAcquire_Failed", file: !10, line: 442)
!491 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkPageAcquireOne", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 382, type: !492, scopeLine: 386, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !153, retainedNodes: !503)
!511 = !DILocation(line: 442, column: 1, scope: !432)
!432 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#338_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 382, type: !11, scopeLine: 386, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagLocalToUnit | DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!153 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !154, retainedTypes: !163, imports: !164, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !27), !dbg !111
label %12
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#39_"**)* @sqliterkValuesAlloc
!27 = !DILabel(scope: !28, name: "sqliterkValuesAlloc_Failed", file: !10, line: 80)
!28 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkValuesAlloc", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 63, type: !29, scopeLine: 64, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !93, retainedNodes: !107)
!111 = !DILocation(line: 80, column: 1, scope: !9)
!9 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#376_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 63, type: !11, scopeLine: 64, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !366), !dbg !375
label %18
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#39_"*, i64)* @sqliterkValuesAddInteger64
!366 = !DILabel(scope: !367, name: "sqliterkValuesAddInteger64_Failed", file: !10, line: 287)
!367 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkValuesAddInteger64", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 267, type: !368, scopeLine: 268, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !93, retainedNodes: !370)
!375 = !DILocation(line: 287, column: 1, scope: !350)
!350 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#363_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 267, type: !11, scopeLine: 268, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !403), !dbg !412
label %18
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#39_"*, double)* @sqliterkValuesAddNumber
!403 = !DILabel(scope: !404, name: "sqliterkValuesAddNumber_Failed", file: !10, line: 317)
!404 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkValuesAddNumber", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 297, type: !405, scopeLine: 298, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !93, retainedNodes: !407)
!412 = !DILocation(line: 317, column: 1, scope: !387)
!387 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#361_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 297, type: !11, scopeLine: 298, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !460), !dbg !473
label %42
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#39_"*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterkValuesAddNoTerminatorText
!460 = !DILabel(scope: !461, name: "sqliterkValuesAddNoTerminatorText_Failed", file: !10, line: 356)
!461 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkValuesAddNoTerminatorText", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 327, type: !462, scopeLine: 330, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !93, retainedNodes: !467)
!473 = !DILocation(line: 356, column: 1, scope: !424)
!424 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#359_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 327, type: !11, scopeLine: 330, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
mismatched subprogram between llvm.dbg.label label and !dbg attachment
  call void @llvm.dbg.label(metadata !496), !dbg !508
label %22
i32 (%"__ir_hidden#39_"*, i8*, i32)* @sqliterkValuesAddBinary
!496 = !DILabel(scope: !497, name: "sqliterkValuesAddBinary_Failed", file: !10, line: 386)
!497 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "sqliterkValuesAddBinary", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 361, type: !498, scopeLine: 362, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !93, retainedNodes: !502)
!508 = !DILocation(line: 386, column: 1, scope: !478)
!478 = distinct !DISubprogram(name: "__hidden#358_", scope: !10, file: !10, line: 361, type: !11, scopeLine: 362, flags: DIFlagPrototyped, spFlags: DISPFlagDefinition | DISPFlagOptimized, unit: !6)
DICompileUnit not listed in llvm.dbg.cu
!93 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C99, file: !7, producer: "Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.29)", isOptimized: true, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !94, retainedTypes: !95, imports: !96, nameTableKind: None)
ld: warning: Invalid debug info found, debug info will be stripped
```

---

**Updated**: Xcode is 11.6 now, the issue still exists.

Answer (score 6):

Also having same trouble. It looks like this was a bug introduced in Xcode 11.4 which is still being tracked by Apple as you can check in https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/130677.

It seems there is no a main solution for this yet.

Comment: Still occurs on xcode 11.6 beta 1, it at least really doesn't prevent app deployment, more just annoying, i filed a FB, but i would suggest others too if possible